# VertX vs Jetty performance issue

Tags: java, jetty, vert.x

I am doing benchmark testing for Jetty and VertX.3 for Asynchronous supported. below is my VertX sample code.

```
public class VertXSampleServer extends AbstractVerticle{
    @Override
    public void start(){
        HttpServer server=vertx.createHttpServer();
        server.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServerRequest request) {
        HttpServerResponse response=request.response();
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
        System.out.println("re received");
        response.putHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(5));
        response.write("Hello");
    }
    }).listen(9091);
  }
}
```

Jetty Sample server:

```
public class JettySampleAsyncServer
{
public static class EmbeddedAsyncServlet extends HttpServlet
{
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
{
final AsyncContext ctxt = req.startAsync();

ctxt.start(new Runnable()
{
@Override
public void run()
{
System.out.println("In AsyncContext / Start / Runnable / run");
ServletResponse response=ctxt.getResponse();
byte[] result="<h1>Hello World</h1>".getBytes();
try {
response.setContentType("text/html");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.setContentLength(result.length);
response.getOutputStream().write(result);

} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
ctxt.setTimeout(new Long(1000));
ctxt.complete();
}
});
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
Server server = new Server();
QueuedThreadPool queuedThreadPool=(QueuedThreadPool) server.getThreadPool();
queuedThreadPool.setMaxThreads(8);
ServerConnector serverConnector=new ServerConnector(server,1,4);
serverConnector.setHost("localhost");
serverConnector.setPort(9090);
//   serverConnector.setAcceptQueueSize(100);
server.addConnector(serverConnector);
ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();
context.setContextPath("/");
ServletHolder asyncHolder = context.addServlet(EmbeddedAsyncServlet.class,"/*");
asyncHolder.setAsyncSupported(true);
server.setHandler(context);
server.start();
server.join();
}
}
```

while testing VertX, I am getting a throughput of 31 requests/min But while Testing Jetty, I am getting 310 req/seconds.
Could anyone exaplin to me the reason for this much high gap in performance. Also, just fyi, I am using Apache Jmeter for Benchmark testing.

Comment: If performance is important for you, I suggest using websockets with a persistent connection.  You can get up to 30,000 requests/second with one connection. If you use a lower level protocol you can achieve a few 100,000/msg per second.

Comment: We are initial phase of design and have to decide which one to choose either jetty or VertX.so I am doing a benchmark testing for them with a sample implementation. Please let me know if I have missed anything

Comment: The 30,000 msg/second I got using Jetty. I suspect the way you are testing that is the problem. e.g. if you create a connection and drop it, this can be orders of magnitude more expensive that the work the server is doing.

Comment: Your servlet isn't using Servlet Async I/O, you are not comparing apples to oranges here.  You are still using blocking I/O in your example.

Comment: Frankly, with this simple testcase, you'd get better performance from Jetty by removing the AsyncContext and using straight / boring servlets. (You would use less threads, and that entire response fits in a single buffer, making Async I/O not very useful either)

Comment: I didn't get you Joakim. Could you correct the if possible?

Comment: Note also, that benchmarks that report req/sec are actually measuring latency.   If you want to know through put, you need to offer a specific through put and report latency.  If the latency is as good as your required Quality of Service, then your server can support that throughput.

Comment: To answer your "I did't get you joakim" question, he is pointing out that there is not much reason to go asynchronous if all you do is start another thread that does blocking  IO.     Always two there are when it comes to async concerns, ie the only point of using async servlets is if you have something else async you need to interact with (async IO, async REST client etc.)

Comment: I understand you now. Also, is the VertX one behaving the same? When I try VertX one with high number of concurrent connections , lets say 150, I see error persistent of 50%. Any idea on what would be going wrong? I have a workstation with 4 cpu cores and 8 logical processors

Comment: You are killing performance by using `System.out.println` in your request handling.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues with your Vert.x implementation, for example you are not ending the connection which will lead to a timeout in order for it to complete.

```
public class VertXSampleServer extends AbstractVerticle {
  @Override
  public void start() {
    HttpServer server=vertx.createHttpServer();
    server.requestHandler(new Handler<HttpServerRequest>() {
      @Override
      public void handle(HttpServerRequest request) {
        HttpServerResponse response=request.response();
        // by default it is 200 so this is optional
        response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
        System.out.println("re received");
        response.putHeader("Content-Length", Integer.toString(5));
        // what you're doing here is wrong you should end the response
        // response.write("Hello");
        response.end("Hello");
        // You should use write if you are going to use chunked responses
        // and the last one should be a end to notify that the request
        // is finished
      }
    }).listen(9091);
  }
}
```

The full documentation on how to handle http response is [here](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/#_sending_back_responses).

It will explain the differences between chunked writes (what you did) and ending a response.

Comment: thanks...i don't see the timeouts now and performance is also improved.